# Redactor image upload not working on laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5, redactor

Same code working in laravel 4 but not working in laravel 5.

Here is all codes :

```
//Redactor Image Upload
Route::post('image/upload', function(){
    $image = Input::file('file');
    $filename = 'bdtimes'.rand(10, 99999999).'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $move = Image::make($image->getRealPath())->save('uploads/images/original/'.$filename);

    if($move){
        return Response::json(['filelink'=>'/uploads/images/original/'. $filename]);
    }else{
        return Response::json(['error'=>true]);
    }
});
```

Redactor Script :

```
$(function()
{
    $('#redactor').redactor({
            focus: true,
            imageUpload: '{{ url() }}/image/upload',
            imageManagerJson: '{{ url() }}/image.php',
            plugins: ['table', 'video','imagemanager','fontcolor','fontsize','fullscreen'],
            maxHeight: 300,
            minHeight: 300
        });
});
```

In Chrome Developer Tool this error showing when i try to upload image.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)        http://localhost:8000/image/upload
```

What is problem ? Please help me .

Thanks

Comment: Does your routing works fine "image/upload". looks from error message it's unable find route

Comment: But what is problem with route ? Everything is right in route . But why this is showing ?

Comment: route seems to be a problem unable to reach to specific route. does all your other routes works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

There is a problem with the token. Change the Redactor script..

```
$(function()
{
    $('#redactor').redactor({
        focus: true,
        imageUpload: '{{ url() }}/image/upload?_token=' + '{{ csrf_token() }}',
        imageManagerJson: '{{ url() }}/image.php',
        plugins: ['table', 'video','imagemanager','fontcolor','fontsize','fullscreen'],
        maxHeight: 300,
        minHeight: 300
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answer . But same error showing.

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Then please check the last log file in `storage/logs` for some more information.

Comment: this is my form ..

http://laravel.io/bin/428P3#44

This is redactor http://imperavi.com/redactor/

Comment: wait, wouldn't an image upload script need to POST? so sending the _token value as a GET variable seems like it wouldn't work.

Comment: wouldn't it be more acceptable to send a POST var with redactor's settings? http://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/settings/images/#setting-uploadImageFields

Answer (score 0):

This means that some line in your route is having an error. Looking at your code I do not see any obvious issue, it could be related to import etc what is not shown here.

Try using dd() after every line to print debugging info until you locate exact line what is broken.

You can also look at the ajax  request response from Chrome Developer Tool as it must have more info about the exact error.

Comment: In chrome developer tools this error showing.

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)        http://localhost:8000/image/upload

My codes is working fine in laravel 4

Comment: You need to look at the request response body. This will contain HTML error page from Laravel which tells you exactly what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when using redactor with yii framework. I think the problem is with setting the route to the upload directory. So the developers of redactor changed some code to prevent this.
In RedactorModule.php > public function getSaveDir() change this:

```
 $path = Yii::getAlias($this->uploadDir);
   if (!file_exists($path)) {
       throw new InvalidConfigException('Invalid config $uploadDir');
  }
   if (FileHelper::createDirectory($path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $this->getOwnerPath(), 0777)) {
  return $path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $this->getOwnerPath();
```

to this:

```
 $path = Yii::getAlias($this->uploadDir) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $this->getOwnerPath();    
   if(!file_exists($path)){      
      if (!FileHelper::createDirectory($path, 0775,$recursive = true )) {
           throw new InvalidConfigException('$uploadDir does not exist and default path creation failed');
       }
      }
  return $path;
```